# PersistanceContext EntityManager NullPointer why?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2, glassfish

I'm trying to configure my engineering project with technologies like :

Glassfish 4.0
Maven
JSF 2.0 
Hibernate 3+
RichFaces 4+
JPA 2.0

Can somebody point me the maven archetype with included technologies? If not could you tell me  which set of jars I need to run it ? I've tried to configured its by normal project but Have issue which looks like that :

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;
  at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getNonTxEMFromCurrentInvocation(EntityManagerWrapper.java:268)
```

Comment: What is "normal project" ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have classpath problem. AbstractMethodError is thrown by JVM when it tries to call abstract method implementation and does not find it. So what do you have:

1. There is old interface EntityManagerFactory, without createEntityManager(SynchronizationType,Map) method
2. And there is old implementation of old EntityManagerFactory interface, called EntityManagerFactory
3. You use new EntityManagerFactory interface, where createEntityManager(SynchronizationType,Map) was added. And Java EE gets an old implementation without it.

Maybe jar hell? Observe carefully all the jar files used by project (I guess you should see into WEB-INF/lib directory inside your deployment path). As they are all just zip files, unpack them and search for org/hibernate/ejb/EntityManagerFactoryImpl.class file. For each jar files, containing this file, use javap to list all methods of EntityManagerFactoryImpl class.